# Sharing a ThreadLocal variable in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, thread-local

In my small application I have threads of two classes - basically writers and readers. Multiple readers can be assigned to a single writer. A writer interacts with its readers by writing to their `chunkBuffer` variable.

Now, I can't quite wrap my head around the thread safety issue here: if I do not store the `chunkBuffer` in a static `ThreadLocal` variable, all readers will share a single chunkBuffer, which is bad. But if I do store the chunkBuffer in a static `ThreadLocal`, the writer, being a separate thread, will get its own copy of the chunkBuffer and will keep writing to it, while none of the data it writes will reach the readers. Can you explain to me what's the problem here? Thank you very much.

**Edit** In other words, is there a way to create a field that will be unique for every single instance of a thread subclass (like ThreadLocal), but can be accessed from other threads on demand?

Comment: Why all readers can't share a single buffer?

Comment: Because a reader may need to drop some of the frames in the buffer, depending on the connection speed between the reader thread and the remote client. So actually readers also write to the buffer in the sense that they can delete content from it.

Comment: I don't see why your writes don't reach the readers if the buffer is written correctly. Actually its not clear to me why you are using ThreadLocal at all, you should be able to avoid it.

Comment: What is the correct way of writing to the buffer, then? Currently I'm calling the reader's addChunk() method from the writer, and naturally it gets executed in the writer's thread, so the reader's copy of chunkBuffer remains untouched.

Comment: You can declare the ThreadLocal variable as volatile.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you have an input writer writing to some buffer and then multiple readers reading this input and sometimes deleting it.  How does the buffer get cleared? After it's been read?  I agree you probably don't need ThreadLocals but perhaps if you explain a little more what you're trying to do we can help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

ThreadLocal is for thread-private data. In your case you need objects to *communicate* so you need other type of objects.

I think the best structure to use is syncrhonized queues: `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue<E>`.

Queues allow a producer to insert data and a consumer to consume from. If it's sync it allow to do it from different threads without breaking the structure.

You can share a queue between the related writers/readers:

```
Writer 1 -> queue 1 -> [readers A/B/C]

Writer 2 -> queue 2 -> [readers D/E/F]
```

Each writer and reader will have its thread. Each reader will try to take one item from its queue blocking if there are no items. If you need to manage more wisely your readers you can try a more sophisticated approach but I think it's a good starting point.

Comment: So, basically, my failure is that instead of allowing readers to read the incoming data in their own thread, I've been trying to push new data into their buffer from the writer (which obviously didn't work)?

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. But a writer executes in its own thread. Readers the same thing. You need a shared-object (sync'ed) where writers can "push" the data and readers can "pop" the data. I talked about queue's with discrete items (<E>) because there are many readers for each writer. If there were 1-to-1 writer-reader pairs they could use some other structure (PipedInputStream + PipedOutputStream).

Comment: Said that. You could integrate both ideas. Writer -> pipe -> UnifiedReader -> queue -> Readers. He he. So the writer can write arbitrary size data. The UnifiedReader always would read say 8k chunks and emit them to the queue to let the readers process them in paralell. But I'm going too far without knowing your application :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use a ThreadLocal variable. You really need a notification mechanism.

Writer does the following:

1. Write to a reader's `chunkBuffer`
2. Notify reader of new data.

There are lots of ways to do this in the java concurrency stuff, but what's usually the easiest and safest is to use an `ArrayBlockingQueue`. In your use case it sounds like each Reader will have its own `ArrayBlockingQueue` and it simply needs to read off the queue.

It of course will depend on your use case. Is it necessary to always work on the latest data or do you need to work on each write to `chunkBuffer`? These kinds of questions are necessary to work out which mechanism you need.

Note: Props to @helios for mentioning synchronous queues, hopefully my answer adds value.

Comment: As I said, I can't write directly to a reader's chunkBuffer from the writer, since chunkBuffer has to be a thread-local variable. Still, I think I really should fix my app so that it works along the lines proposed by @helios.

Comment: Why do you say chunkBuffer has to be a thread-local variable? Can it be a private variable in your reader object and achieve the same purpose? Thread-local is intended for things that do not exit or enter the thread, such as guaranteeing each thread has its own unique Random object.